# Count number of lines in the input

Tags: c

I was trying to calculate the number of lines in the input given by the user. There is no error shown by the compiler, but still I  get no output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 main()
{
    int c,in;
     in=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            ++in;
        }
    }
    printf("The no of lines are %d",in);
 }
```

Comment: Input EOF (ctrl+Z for windows or ctrl+D for *nix)

Comment: It should work as long as you provide EOF in your input

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: the signature for `main()` is `int main( void )`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, please indent the code consistently

Comment: the posted code has a logic error.  Note what happens when the user inputs some characters, then inputs a EOF rather than a '\n' followed by EOF.  I.E. the line count will be 1 too small

Comment: Suggest the code use the function: `fgets()` rather than `getchar()`  the loop would be: `char buffer[1024]; while( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) ) { n++; }` and  no need to correct 'n' for a final line.  Of course this assumes that no input line will be greater than 1023 characters in length.

Comment: I will keep these mistakes in mind -user3629249,appreciate it.